# Escape single quotes in Azure Search query

Tags: api, search, filter, azure-cognitive-search

I am having a single quote in the data in filter condition.

Example: David O'Neil.

So If we have give this in Search Explorer as,

> *&$count=true&$filter=Name eq 'David O'Neil'

How can we escape that single quote in the filter.

**Update 1:** If we use single quote to escape that one, 0 records are coming.

**Update 2:** Not able to use backslashes() also.

Answer (score 11):

Single quotes in OData filters are escaped by doubling:

```
$filter=Name eq 'David O''Neil'
```

Since that resulted in zero records for you, I would guess there are other issues with your data (perhaps the apostrophe in O'Neil is not the ASCII character 39 but something more ornate?)

Comment: Doubling the single quotes does not seem to work for me. I get [AzureSearchServiceRESTCallException: {"error":{"code":"","message":"Invalid expression: Syntax error: character '\\' is not valid...   It tries to escape with two back slashes in the expression. don't becomes  /.*don\\'\\'t.*/

Comment: @VivekAyer That expression looks like a Lucene regex query, not a filter. Only the filter parameter uses the OData syntax, and the above answer is not applicable in other contexts. If you're still having trouble, please post a separate question.